# VBA ACE issue with Oracle Decimal

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

We use VBA to retrieve data from an Oracle database using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.

We have used this method without issue for a long time, but we have encountered a problem with a specific query of data from a specific table.

When running it under VBA, we get "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.  However investigating further, we find the following:

The queries we run are dynamically generated, and how we handle them is to read the results into a variant array, then output that array into Excel.  When we step-through our particular query, we find that one specific database field is "blank": The locals window shows the value to be completely blank:  it is not an empty string, it is not a null, it is not zero.  VarType() shows it to be a decimal data type, and yet it is empty.

I can't seem to prevent this error from locking-out:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

...still breaks.

```
if (isEmpty(theValue)) then
```

...doesn't catch it, because it is not empty

```
if (theValue is nothing) then
```

...doesn't catch it because it is not an object

etc.

We used the SQL in the a .NET application, and got a more informative error:

> Decimal's scale value must be between 0 and 28, inclusive.  Parameter name: Scale

So:  I see this as two issues:
1.) In VBA, how do I trap the variant datatype value-that-is-not-empty-or-null, and;
2.) How do I resolve the Oracle Decimal problem?

For #2, I see from the Oracle [decimal data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html), it can support precision of up to 31 places, and I assume that the provider I am using can only support 28.  I guess I need to Cast it to a smaller type in the query.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you just `CopyFromRecordset` instead of using an array? Something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: can you manipulate the query against the Oracle database to include a NVL(_[field]_, 0) on that particular field so it can't become "empty"

Comment: @barrowc: Because of the nature of the dynamic query, that would be a major re-write.

Comment: @MikeD:  The underlying data isn't empty; it's just a decimal that is too long for the provider to handle.  I managed to fix it via:  `CAST(ZV_PERF_INT_SPLIT_DAY_PROD.ALLOC_COND_VOL_STM3 AS decimal(20,10)) AS COND`

Comment: @barrowc:  I managed to bodge it to test it.  I get an error message _CopyFromRecordset Failed_